# Moving all elements with class ".something" in plain javascriot

Tags: javascript, html, css

I managed to get a `div id = "box"` to move in the browser with arrow keys. Now I want to make every `div id = "box"` with class `.something` to move also.

I have try loop over the code with `querySelectorAll` but the code always fail.
Can someone help me out? And tell me how to do it because now I feel lost totally. The code below works just with one div id

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
var key = event.key;
var left = box.offsetLeft;
var top = box.offsetTop;

console.log("left: ", left);
console.log("top: ", top);


    box.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
    box.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
    box.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
    box.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
var step = 10;

switch (key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
        event.preventDefault();
        box.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
        break;
    case "ArrowDown":
        event.preventDefault();
        box.style.top = (top + step) + "px";
        break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
        box.style.left = (left - step) + "px";
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        box.style.left = (left + step) + "px";
        break;
}
console.log("You pressed on: ", key);
```

});

Comment: Unlike classes, all your IDs should have their own unique name hence why your code only works with just one div with the id `box`.

Comment: to move all box ids with class .something. Then I need to use a for loop right? but how do I connect the add.eventListener to the for loop. This is where I am failing

Comment: each id must be unique, you can't have 2 id="box" even if they use different class.
For your problem, you can use event delegation, but this suppose  to have the same parent for all your moving elements, when one of them get the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a stab at fixing it. 
Repl can be found here: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/FrightenedAgileBrain

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  var key = event.key;  

  for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var box = boxes[i];
    var left = box.offsetLeft;
    var top = box.offsetTop;    
    console.log("left: ", left);
    console.log("top: ", top);   

    var step = 10;

    switch (key) {
        case "ArrowUp":
            event.preventDefault();
            box.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            event.preventDefault();
            box.style.top = (top + step) + "px";
            break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
            box.style.left = (left - step) + "px";
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            box.style.left = (left + step) + "px";
            break;
    } 
    console.log("You pressed on: ", key);  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was very close to this example. I just had to many [i] on the variables. Awesome thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Because querySelector all will give you an array as a result, you can't just change it easily, you have to iterate over all of the objects.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.something');
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
var key = event.key;
var step = 10;
for(let el of elements){
  let left = el.offsetLeft;
  let top = el.offsetTop;
  el.style.top = (top - step) + "px";

switch (key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
        event.preventDefault();
        el.style.top = (top - step) + "px";
        break;
    case "ArrowDown":
        event.preventDefault();
        el.style.top = (top + step) + "px";
        break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
        el.style.left = (left - step) + "px";
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        el.style.left = (left + step) + "px";
        break;
}
}

console.log("You pressed on: ", key);
});
```

Also, I recommend trying out jQuery, it makes these sorts of things much simpler. Especially for beginners it's easier to understand, but you should be careful not to forget the "vanilla" way to do it.